# Is there a better way to compare nullable dates?

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

i am trying to determine if there is a difference between 2 nullable dates . . is there a more elegant ways instead of this:

```
  if (newDate.HasValue && (!oldDate.HasValue ||  (oldDate.HasValue && oldDate.Value.Date != mewDate.Value.Date)))
```

Comment: It looks like you've got some relatively complicated and asymmetric rules there, so I'm not really surprised that you need to write them out in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# compiler automatically lifts logical operators like `==` and `!=` over nullalbe types, so you can usually compare them directly instead of checking `HasValue`. In this case, you can compare with `!=` once you have checked that `newDate` is not null.

```
if(newDate.HasValue && newDate != oldDate)
```

It is described in the specification:

> **7.3.7 Lifted operators**
>
> Lifted operators permit predefined and user-defined operators that
>   operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable
>   forms of those types.
>
> For the equality operators 
>   ==  != a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool.The
>   lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each
>   operand type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and
>   a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are
>   non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the
>   underlying operator to produce the bool result.

Comment: Possibly he simply meant `if (newDate != oldDate)`. I know his expression wasn't equivalent to that, but that is all it takes to check if there is any "difference".